# How do I authenticate with firebase admin sdk?

Tags: authentication, firebase-admin

I have a Firebase Realtime Database. I have a user with an email and password:

[image]

I also have some rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    "blogposts": {
      ".write": "auth !== null"
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see from the rules, I don't want anybody writing to blogposts unless auth is not null. I'm assuming that if I can sign in using the user credentials above, auth will not be null (correct me if I'm wrong).

I'm using the Firebase Admin SDK on my server. I generated a key file from here:

[image]

The key file is sitting on my server and I'm using it to initialize Firebase Admin:

```
const serviceAccount = require('my-key-file.json');
fbadmin.initializeApp({
    credential: fbadmin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: '...'
});
```

At this point, I'm not sure how to authenticate with the user credentials above. How can I 1) authenticate with the user above and 2) set auth in the rules above to not null? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Admin SDKs do not support user authentication operations. You must you one of the Firebase client SDKs for that (Android, IOS, Web etc). Furthermore, database requests originating from the Admin SDK are not validated by the Security Rules by default. Although you can get the SDK to issue database requests, as if they were coming from a specific pre-defined user: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start#authenticate-with-limited-privileges

Comment: Thanks Hiranya. I guess I'll go with Cloud Firestore instead.

Comment: It has the exact same semantics when it comes to Admin SDK and security rules. So you will probably encounter the same issues there.